# Ruby Pronto Gem pretty formatting?

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to get better formatting output from Pronto?  As an example, the brakeman gem when run directly can give me nice HTML formatted output, but when I run pronto runner plugins everything gets stuffed into a basic text file with very little structure.

Comment: Why use a gem for formatting when you can use string interpolation?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there are [10 formatters](https://github.com/mmozuras/pronto/tree/master/lib/pronto/formatter) available at `pronto` master branch.
Run `pronto help run` to list all available formatters.

As far as I know, currently there is no HTML formatter.
You can use `checkstyle` formatter to generate XML which might be used by CI server like Jenkins to generate HTML report.

If none of available formatters satisfy your needs, you can implement your own formatter.
For reference implementation check out simple [text formatter](https://github.com/mmozuras/pronto/blob/master/lib/pronto/formatter/text_formatter.rb) and [GitHub](https://github.com/mmozuras/pronto/blob/master/lib/pronto/formatter/github_formatter.rb) formatter.